# How to expose securely a Node.js/Express server into the real world?

Tags: security, node.js, attacks, vulnerability

Essentially I would like to know what the title suggests. Node.js/Express is nice. However, node is a fairly recent thing and hence there may be security risks by exposing the server to the real world. So, my question really boils down to what sort of things should one be careful about when exposing node to the rest of the world and what necessary (or advised) procedures should one follow in order to run a node server online and avoid, to the extent possible, successful vulnerability attacks from others, security breaches, and so on.

Thanks in advance for your help.

(I am reposting here what I previously [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19755165/how-to-expose-securely-a-node-js-express-server-into-the-real-world) on StackOverflow.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well to give you some context on Node.js: It's production ready.

- Yahoo! just announced they're redoing Yahoo in Node.js They mentioned many things are already in Node
- WalMart Labs is using it to proxy all their traffic. They used it as the first line to help manage the traffic load on black friday. #nodebf on Twitter. *Contributed [HAPI](https://github.com/spumko/hapi)*
- Paypal is switching to Node and has many parts running in it already. *Contributed [Kraken.](http://krakenjs.com/)*

Node itself can act as a web server, proxy, app, etc. If these large corporations are using Node.js they are making large investments in resources.

Comment: Thank you for your time. This was also my decision back in November and now that I know the above three bullets I feel better. :)